# python subprocess module can't parse filename with special characters "("

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, special-characters, file-not-found

I have a Python program that reads files and then tars them into tar balls of a certain size.

One of my files not only has spaces in it but also contains parentheses.  I have the following code:

```
cmd = "/bin/tar -cvf " +  tmpname +  " '" + filename + "'"
```

NOTE: Those are single quotes inside double quotes outside of the filename variable.  It's a little difficult to see.

Where `tmpname` and `filename` are variables in a for-loop that are subject to change each iteration (irrelevant).

As you can see the filename I'm tarballing contains single quotes around the file name so that the shell (bash) interprets it literally as is and doesn't try to do variable substitution which "" will do or program execution which ` will do.

As far as I can see, the `cmd` variable contains the exact syntax for the shell to interpret the command as I want it to.  However when I run the following subprocess command substituting the cmd variable:

```
cmdobj = call(cmd, shell=True)
```

I get the following output/error:

> /bin/tar: 237-r Property Transport Request (PTR) 012314.pdf: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>
> /bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
>
> unable to tar: 237-r Property Transport Request (PTR) 012314.pdf

I even print the command out to the console before running the subprocess command to see what it will look when running in the shell and it's:

```
cmd: /bin/tar -cvf tempname0.tar '237-r Property Transport Request (PTR) 012314.pdf'
```

When I run the above command in the shell as is it works just fine.  Not really sure what's going on here.  Help please!

Comment: You don't need shell=True, pass a list of separate args

Comment: I do need shell=True.  if I leave out shell=True or have shell=False (which it defaults to if you leave out shell altogether) it gives this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packnmove.py", line 195, in <module>
    main()
  File "packnmove.py", line 74, in main
    cmdobj = call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

Comment: you need to pass a list of args when not using shell=True

Comment: you don't need `subbprocess` here. There is `tarfile` module in Python stdlib: `with tarfile.open(tmpname, 'w') as archive: archive.add(filename)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a `list` of `args` without `shell=True` and the **full path** to the file if running from a different directory:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["tar","-cvf",tmpname ,"Property Transport Request (PTR) 012314.pdf"])
```

Also use `tar` not `'bin/tar'`. [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) will raise a `CalledProcessError` if the command returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: yes you're correct!  I figured it out before I saw your answer but thank you!

Comment: @DerekDub, no worries, you should always generally pass a list of args avoiding using shell=True

Comment: @DerekDub, are you using python2.6?

Answer (score 2):

The [`call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) method that is part of the subprocess module should have an array of strings passed.

On the command line you would call

```
tar -cvf "file folder with space/"
```

The following is equivalent in python

```
call(["tar", "-cvf", "file folder with space/"])
```

You are making this call in the shell

```
"tar -cvf 'file folder with space/'"
```

Which causes the shell to look for a program with the exact name as `tar -cvf 'file folder with space/'

This avoids string concatenation, which makes for cleaner code.